# google chrome extension timer reset

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, timer, reset

I want to build a Google Chrome extension, which check the mouse movement.

If the mouse didn't moved until 5 minutes (in the code I set 0.1 and 0.2 because I won't want wait lots always in the test time), the extension open other site (the code just show an alert box).

My problem is that, I can't re-set the Alarm if the mouse is moving. Everything is work properly, just I can restart or re-set the Alarm what I create.

I know I did something wrong.

This is the first time when I try made a Google Chrome extension, but I programmed until now in php, vb.net, html, vbscript.

But that alarm re-set don't want work under Google Chrome Ver. 63. (even if I try in older version too and under chromium also, but it didn't worked).

Thanks for your support ^^

The code start here :

**MANIFEST.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "Chrome-extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
     "alarms"   
   ],
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://www.google.hu/*"],
        "js": ["jquery1.7.2.js", "detectclicks.js"]
      }
   ],
  "description": "Chrome-extension",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
     } 
   }
```

**DETECTCLICKS.JS** (when the mouse is move, its re-set the alarm. Delete and Recreate)

```
$('html').on('mousemove', '*',function(event) {
    chrome.alarms.clearAll();
    chrome.alarms.create("myAlarm", {delayInMinutes: 0.1, 
    periodInMinutes: 0.2});
    alert("OK");
});
```

**BACKGROUND.JS** (if the alarm is starting, show a short message - just because of check)

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    alert("Beep");
});
```

**POPUP.JS** (Turn on and Turn off the extensions with alarms start and stop)

```
var alarmClock = {

    onHandler : function(e) {
        chrome.alarms.create("myAlarm", {
            delayInMinutes: 0.1, 
            periodInMinutes: 0.2
        });
        window.close();
    },

    offHandler : function(e) {
        chrome.alarms.clear("myAlarm");
        window.close();
    },

    setup: function() {
        var a = document.getElementById('alarmOn');
        a.addEventListener('click', alarmClock.onHandler);
        var a = document.getElementById('alarmOff');
        a.addEventListener('click', alarmClock.offHandler);
    }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    alarmClock.setup();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In prod you can't set alarm < 1 minute and in new version of chrome you can't set this alarm in developer mode.

> In order to reduce the load on the user's machine, Chrome limits alarms to at most once every 1 minute but may delay them an arbitrary amount more. That is, setting delayInMinutes or periodInMinutes to less than 1 will not be honored and will cause a warning. when can be set to less than 1 minute after "now" without warning but won't actually cause the alarm to fire for at least 1 minute.

[chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms#type-Alarm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) Then i try find other way to solve this problem.

Comment: You can try use js [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: I tried, but it didnt worked under Chrome extension. That is why i used alarm function. The alarm function working perfectly, just i cant reset it :) now i try on that way, i memorise the actual time when the mouse is moving (forexample 12:32:21 (hours:minutes:seconds)) and i add +5 ,minutes (so i've got 12:37:21), and if the actual time reach the second variable (12:37:21), so until that time the mouse not move, i've got a alert message. In this way maybe will works ^^ by the way really thanks your help :)